# EC2 Instance not available in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have created an EC2 instance via Terraform with the following configuration:

1. EC2 instance is using the latest Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux 2 AMI.
2. Instance is sitting in a private subnet, with a route to a NAT GW. Tested internet connectivity fine.
3. SG rules are configured correctly.
4. EC2 Instance profile is using AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role
5. EC2 user-data is configured (with my cluster name) with:

   echo ECS_CLUSTER=my-cluster-name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config

When I go to my ecs-cluster, no instances show in the EC2 Instance section of the console.

Is there anything else I'm missing as to why this cluster can't register with the EC2 instance?

Comment: I would start by logging into the server over SSH, and checking that `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` actually has that `ECS_CLUSTER` setting in it. If that's correct then I would check the ECS agent log on the EC2 server, which I believe is in `/var/log/ecs/`

Comment: "Unable to register as a container instance with ECS: RequestError: send request failed\ncaused by: Post \"https://ecs.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/\": net/http: request canceled while waiting for 
connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" module=client.go

The EC2 instance has ALL Traffic outbound and the ECS cluster is configured with an ALB that allows 443

Comment: The ECS cluster's ALB is not involved in the EC2 instance registration. That would be entirely between the EC2 instance and the public AWS API. I would try to run something like `aws ecs describe-clusters` from inside the EC2 instance to test connectivity.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you for your comments. So i'd misconfigured my terraform code and was accidentally deploying the EC2 cluster in my public subnet. I didn't configure an EIP so the instance was sitting in a public subnet with no public ipv4. Deployed it in the private subnet and worked straight away. D'oh!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!